# Function call for getBalance not working

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, react, typescript

I tried to call a getter function from my contract but getting an error: too many arguments and not sure if I'm using the correct syntax

From contract.sol

```
// mapping
mapping(address => mapping(bytes32 => uint256)) private s_traderBalances;

// getter function
function getBalance(bytes32 ticker) external view returns(uint256) {
    return s_traderBalances[msg.sender][ticker];
}
```

From my context

```
const fetchBalances = useCallback(
    async (address: string, ticker: string) => {
      if (account) {
        const signer = accountProvider?.getSigner();
        const contractWithSigner = contract?.connect(signer);
        < ! ----- Error on this syntax ---- >
        try {
          const balance = await contractWithSigner?.getBalance(
            ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(ticker)
          );

          setCurrentBalance(balance.toString());
          console.log(balance);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
       < ! ----- Error on this syntax ---- >

        try {
          const tokenB = await tokens[ticker]?.balanceOf(signer.getAddress());
          setTokenBalance(tokenB);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    },
    [contract, tokens, account, accountProvider]
  );
```

This is the error message from the console

Error: too many arguments: passed to contract (count=1, expectedCount=0, code=UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)

My test script was passed successfully but still i have my doubts :)

Comment: Your smartContract code looks good. The issue has to be with the script that tries to call it. Keep in mind that bytes32 values need to start with 0x and contain only hexadecimal characters (when you are sending it to smartContract)

Comment: Post you ABI, specifically getBalance

Comment: {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getBalance",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },

Comment: thank you for the hint. Seems the abi wasnt updated to the frontend and manage to display it after I've copied a new one